# Adding Labels to the Left or Right of Highcharts Funnel Visualization

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

My current visualization is as follows:

```js
$(function() {
  var dataEx = [
      ['1 Visit', 352000],
      ['2 Visits', 88000],
      ['3+ Visits', 42000]
    ],
    len = dataEx.length,
    sum = 0,
    minHeight = 0.05,
    data = [];
    
   //specify your percent of prior visit value manually here:
   
   var perc = [100, 25, 48];

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    sum += dataEx[i][1];
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var t = dataEx[i],
      r = t[1] / sum;
    data[i] = {
      name: t[0],
      y: (r > minHeight ? t[1] : sum * minHeight),
      percent: perc[i],   // <----- this here is manual input
   //percent: Math.round(r * 100),    <--- this here is mathematical
      label: t[1]
    }
  }
  console.log(dataEx, data)
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'funnel',
      marginRight: 100,


      events: {
        load: function() {
          var chart = this;
          Highcharts.each(chart.series[0].data, function(p, i) {
           var bBox = p.dataLabel.getBBox()
            p.dataLabel.attr({
              x: (chart.plotWidth - chart.plotLeft) / 2,
              'text-anchor': 'middle',
              y: p.labelPos.y - (bBox.height / 2)
            })
          })
        },
        redraw: function() {
          var chart = this;
          Highcharts.each(chart.series[0].data, function(p, i) {
            p.dataLabel.attr({
              x: (chart.plotWidth - chart.plotLeft) / 2,
              'text-anchor': 'middle',
              y: p.labelPos.y - (bBox.height / 2)
            })
          })
        }
      },
    },

    title: {
      text: 'Guest Return Funnel',
      x: -50
    },
    tooltip: {
      //enabled: false
      formatter: function() {
        return '<b>' + this.key +
          '</b><br/>Percent of Prior Visit: '+ this.point.percent + '%<br/>Guests: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.label, 0);
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {


        allowPointSelect: true,
        borderWidth: 12,

        animation: {
          duration: 400
        },


        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,

          connectorWidth: 0,
          distance: 0,

          formatter: function() {
            var point = this.point;
            console.log(point);
            return '<b>' + point.name + '</b> (' + Highcharts.numberFormat(point.label, 0) + ')<br/>' + point.percent + '%';
          },
          minSize: '10%',
          color: 'black',
          softConnector: true
        },

        neckWidth: '30%',
        neckHeight: '0%',
        width: '50%',
        height: '110%'


        //old options are as follows:

        //neckWidth: '50%',
        //neckHeight: '50%',
        //-- Other available options
        //height: '200'
        // width: pixels or percent
      }
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Unique users',
      data: data
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/funnel.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="width: 500px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

I would like to do the following (a photo that clarifies what I would like is [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rz2Qy.jpg)):

1. Put the category names "1 Visit", "2 Visits", "3 Visits" to the LEFT of
   the funnel.
2. Arrange the number of guest amount and percent for each category of the 
   funnel so that it appears like (INSIDE the funnel):

   352K   100%

   Right now I have the values as the full number like 352000 but I'm
   wondering if there's a way to make all numbers with 000 at the end into
   a "K" at the end.

   It would be great if I could also add labels for those two values AT THE
   TOP of the funnel ("Guests" and "Percent of Prior Visit").
3. Add 2 more labels to the RIGHT of the funnel called "Q1/17 TTM" and "Avg 
   Value" and have values be placed for each category of the funnel
   below the labels. The values for "Q1/17 TTM" should be red and the 
   values for "Avg Value" should be gray.

   The values for "Q1/17 TTM" begin at the "2 Visits" and end at the very
   bottom (under the last category)

   Values for "Avg Value" begin at the first category and end at the last
   category.
4. At the very bottom of the visualization, have a value. Don't worry about 
   what this is (and this is the value $12.9M in the photo).

And I want these changes to still make the data processing algorithm to visualize small values work. I would really appreciate the help! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn not any option in Highcharts to handle more than one datalabels, but you can use **text SVGRenderer** to add additional text elements, for example:

```
        events: {
            render: function() {
                var chart = this;
                Highcharts.each(chart.series[0].data, function(p, i) {
                    var bBox = p.dataLabel.getBBox();
                    p.dataLabel.attr({
                        x: (chart.plotWidth - chart.plotLeft) / 2,
                        'text-anchor': 'middle',
                        y: p.labelPos.y - (bBox.height / 2)
                    });

                    if (p.dataLabel1) {
                        p.dataLabel1.destroy();
                        p.dataLabel2.destroy();
                    }

                    p.dataLabel1 = chart.renderer.text(p.name, p.dataLabel.x - 150, p.dataLabel.y + chart.plotTop - bBox.y).add();

                    p.dataLabel2 = chart.renderer.text('some Text', p.dataLabel.x + 150, p.dataLabel.y + chart.plotTop - bBox.y).add();
                });
            }
        }
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w2cs4ufe/1/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#text